# Pass an intent from Activities

Tags: android, android-intent

I am implementing a `LoginActivity` registering a new Account online. After login or registration I start a new intent and try to pass the new account data back to `MainActivity`:

```
Toast.makeText(context,"SUCCESS",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    finish();
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("username",mUsername);
        myIntent.putExtra("email",mEmail);                  
    LoginActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

The idea is that I want to receive the data in `MainActivity` so that I can add username and email in the navigation drawer's header. Inside `MainActivity` I have the fields:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{
    String NAME = "Sign in";
    String EMAIL = "";

  //... ... ...  
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  //... ... ...  

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if(intent.getStringExtra("username")!=null){
        setAccount(intent);
    }
    firstTime();
  }
  public void setAccount(Intent intent){
        NAME = intent.getStringExtra("username");
        EMAIL = intent.getStringExtra("email");
  }   
}
```

}

but after I login/register the intent is not returning my data back to the `MainActivity`...

What is the problem?

*** ***EDIT*** ***

I implemented this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_ACCOUNT_REQUEST);
```

instead of

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
finish();
```

In `LoginActivity` inside `onPostExecute()` (I use an AsyncTask):

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
finish();
myIntent.putExtra("username",mUsername);
myIntent.putExtra("email",mEmail)
setResult(1, myIntent);
LoginActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

and again inside `MainActivity` I implemented the `onActivityResult()` method but when it's executed the `Intent data` received result is null. what's wrong with my code?

*** EDIT2 ***

I solved it by removing the `LoginActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent)` as suggested by @lqbal:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
 returnIntent.putExtra("username",mUsername);
 returnIntent.putExtra("email",mEmail);
 setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
 finish();
```

**But there lies one more problem:** 
in the method `onActivityResult()` I try to assign the received data to the class' fields with no success. More details below.

In the beginning of the `MainActivity` class I assign two variables:

```
String NAME = "Sign in", EMAIL = "";
```

These two values are inserted in my navigation drawer. So after I receive the result from `LoginActivity` I want to update these two fields in the navigation drawer and display to the user its username and password, and I try to do it this way:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    // Check which request we're responding to
    if (requestCode == PICK_ACCOUNT_REQUEST) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // The user picked a contact.
            String usr = data.getStringExtra("username");
            String mal = data.getStringExtra("email");
            this.NAME = usr;this.EMAIL=mal;
        }
    }
}
```

with no success, in fact after completion of `LoginActivity` I still visualize the old values. Why?

Comment: if `LoginActivity` is started from `MainActivity`, then you should use `startActivityForResult()` and use `setResult(int, Bundle)` method in `LoginActivity`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `startActivityForResult();` to start the activity to get the results from started activity back to the starting activity.

Edit:
Follow this, it shall fix your issue

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("username",mUsername); 
returnIntent.putExtra("email",mEmail); 
setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
finish();
```

You are starting the activity to get the result, so just create an intent, set the result and finish the activity, no need to start activity again.

Comment: Move the finish() method after all the intent operations, it shall fix your problem. If yes then mark my answer as accepted.

Comment: Just noticed your code. Remove LoginActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent); from your edited code then it shall work. As you had started activity for a result no need to start activity again. Just finish the activity and it shall return the result to the starting activity onActivityResult(). If it works then accept my answer.

Comment: Edited the answer with code to fix issue. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, it's working! But there's still one issue: once the method `onActivityResult` gets the `Intent data` result, I can't update the class' fields with the acquired data (`NAME` and `EMAIL`). I try to assign them but my UI keeps displaying the old values. Is it possible to update the fields of the class without restarting the Activity?

Comment: If this worked please accept the answer. And as your issue is concerned, How are you setting the values to class? Provide detail so that I shall help you.

Comment: Thank you, I accepted your first answer... but I still have a problem (see last EDIT2). Please help

Comment: You can also answer me here to get extra points: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775020/update-ui-from-intent-result

Comment: Have answered there, hope it helps you

Answer (score 1):

put `finish();` after `startActivity()`