# How to set an Observer to Update Navigation Drawer after onActivityResult method's received an Intent result

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation-drawer, observer-pattern, android-recyclerview

In my app I want to update the Navigation Drawer with the username's nickname and email after he's logged in.

From my `MainActivity` I am starting a `LoginActivity` with the                    `startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_ACCOUNT_REQUEST);` method
to get the users registered or logged in.

After the `LoginActivity` returns the `Intent data` result (his `NAME` and `EMAIL`) back to `MainActivity`, the method `onActivityResult()` is called and there I try to update the class' global variables `NAME` and  `EMAIL` with the newly received data, with no success: after every registration or log the two fields never show in the navigation drawer. Here's my code:

In the beginning of the `MainActivity` class I assign two variables:

```
String NAME = "Sign in", EMAIL = "";
```

These two values are inserted in my navigation drawer. After I receive the result from `LoginActivity` I want to update these two fields in the `onActivityResult()` method. This way:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    // Check which request we're responding to
    if (requestCode == PICK_ACCOUNT_REQUEST) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // The user picked a contact.
            String usr = data.getStringExtra("username");
            String mal = data.getStringExtra("email");
            this.NAME = usr;this.EMAIL=mal;
        }
    }
}
```

with no success, in fact after completion of `LoginActivity` I still visualize the old values within the Navigation Drawer because I'm not able to access the 2 EditText holding Username and Password from `MainActivity`. In fact the 2 EditText are managed inside `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`.

How can I set an Observer or something similar to dinamically update my Navigation Drawer's RecyclerView.Adapter?

More details below

*** EDIT ***

Ps. My Navigation Drawer is implemented with RecyclerView, I therefore have a `RecyclerView.Adapter` class and a `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` class inside the adapter. In `MainActivity` I have this code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{
    ArrayList<DrawerItem> dataList; 
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;                // Declaring RecyclerView
    RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;              // Declaring Adapter For Recycler View
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager; // Declaring Layout Manager as a linear layout manager
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private CharSequence mTitle, mDrawerTitle;
    Toolbar toolbar;

    String NAME, EMAIL; int AVATARresID; //TODO update Navigation Drawer fields

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        /* Assigning the toolbar object to the view
        and setting the the Action bar to our toolbar */
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); //pulsante drawer
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);      //pulsante dietro

        //Initializing
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        AVATARresID = R.mipmap.aka;
        // Add Drawer Item to dataList
        dataList = new ArrayList<>();
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem(NAME,EMAIL,AVATARresID));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Account", R.mipmap.ic_account));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Tuoi Tour", R.mipmap.ic_events));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Prenota Tour", R.mipmap.ic_action_search));
        // dataList.add(new DrawerItem("My Favorites")); // adding a header to the list
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Others")); // adding a header to the list
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Contatti", R.mipmap.ic_about));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Tutorial", R.mipmap.ic_help));

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(dataList, mSelectedPositions);

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerLayout,toolbar,
            R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close){
                    @Override 
                    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {...}
                    @Override
                    public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {...}
        };


        // Drawer Listener set to the Drawer toggle
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState(); 
        mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
            new RecyclerItemClickListener(this, mRecyclerView, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {...});

    }
}
```

Comment: You have to update the views with datas
tvEmail.setText(this.EMAIL);
tvName.setText(this.NAME);

Comment: I tried it but it goes it NullPointerException. Since my NavigationDrawer has been implemented with RecyclerView, and the 2 TextViews (which I am supposed to update) are assigned to the xml in another class (the RecyclerView adapter). Precisely, within the RecyclerView.ViewHolder class also inside the RecyclerView.Adapter class.... Is there another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved it!

My solution is twofold: I both update the `dataList` dataStructure on the fly after the user's login, and then make this update persistent with `SharedPreferences`.

The reason why the following instructions were not working:

```
String usr = data.getStringExtra("username");
String mal = data.getStringExtra("email");
this.NAME = usr; this.EMAIL=mal;
```

was because the `RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter` (the object holding my data) did not have any way to know that a certain change took place, and it therefore didn't update its data.

For it to know that a certain change had actually occurred, first of all I had to modify the `ArrayList<DrawerItems> dataList`, and secondly I had to notify the `Adapter` of the change with the method `mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(0)` (similarly to how it happens with the Observer-Observable pattern). This way the Navigation Drawer is immediately updated with the new `dataList`.

This wasn't all. Simply updating the `dataList` on the fly was a volatile solution, since every time the user changes activity and then goes back to the `MainActivity`, the NavigationDrawer is initialized again with the old data (losing any acquired information during past states, and therefore loading empty NAME and EMAIL variables). Thus, in order to make the account information persistent was necessary to save them into `SharedPreferences`.

This is the code of `onActivityResult()` updating the navigation drawer on the fly and also saving the account's information persistently into `SharedPreferences`:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    // Check which request we're responding to
    if (requestCode == PICK_ACCOUNT_REQUEST) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // The user picked a contact.
            String usr = data.getStringExtra("username");
            String mail = data.getStringExtra("email");

            SharedPreferences usrData = getSharedPreferences(usr_loggedin, MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = usrData.edit();
            editor.clear();
            editor.putBoolean("usraccount",true).commit();
            editor.putString("username",usr).commit();
            editor.putString("email",mail).commit();

            dataList.remove(0);
            dataList.add(0,new DrawerItem(usr,mail,AVATARresID));
            mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(0);
        }
    }
}
```

This is where in `MainActivity` I check if the user is logged in, and if so the account information are loaded from SharedPreferences:

```
//...
String NAME,EMAIL; int AVATARresID;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //...

    //Initializing
    SharedPreferences usrData = getSharedPreferences(usr_loggedin, MODE_PRIVATE);
    AVATARresID = R.mipmap.aka;
    // Add Drawer Item to dataList
    dataList = new ArrayList<>();
    dataList = prepareDatalist(dataList, NAME, EMAIL, AVATARresID);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(dataList, mSelectedPositions);

    if(usrData.contains("usraccount")){
        String usr,mail;
        usr = usrData.getString("username",usr_loggedin);
        mail = usrData.getString("email",usr_loggedin);
        dataList.remove(0);
        dataList.add(0,new DrawerItem(usr,mail,AVATARresID));
        mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(0);
    }

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    //... ...
}
```

As a side not, to solve my problems I had to notice (with a great deal of debugging) that after the method `onActivityResult()` has finished, the MainActivity's `onCreate()` is not called a second time and the execution of the class ends with the end of `onActivityResult()`.

For this reason I couldn't rely only on `SharedPreferences` to update the user's information. In fact even though the `SharedPreferences` do their job well by making all the needed information available everywhere in the project, when the `onCreate` method isn't called a second time, there would be no way of update the `RecyclerView.Adapter` with the new information and no extra code, making the `SharedPreferences` to become pointless.

For these reasons, updating `MainActivity`'s account fields was impossible to perform without the `mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(0)`, which did the job on the fly.

Having said that, any subsequent call to `onCreate()` method in `MainActivity` would load the account information from `SharedPreferences()` until the user wouldn't logout somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment, so posting as an answer - you are updating the variables, but are you updating the `DrawerLayout`'s view itself? I assume you have some kind of `TextViews` or `EditTexts` for the Strings, are you calling `.setText(NAME)`/`.setText(EMAIL)` on them? Can't quite make this out from your question. :)

Answer (score 1):

In your navigation drawer I believe you are using the textviews to display the name and email. You need to pass these values with the help of a listener and then set these texts in the drawer text views.

Create a listener which has a method which takes name and email

```
public interface ChangeListener {
     void displayNameAndEmail(String name, String email );
}
```

You implement this listener in the drawer menu and set the text views in this method based on the values received.

```
@Override 
private void displayNameAndEmail(String name, String email ) {
      mEmailTextView.setText(email);
      mNameTextView.setText(name);
};
```

In your onActivityResult() call this method and pass the values

```
ChangeListener.displayNameAndEmail(name, email );
```

Comment: I tried it but it goes it `NullPointerException`, I think that your code doesn't suit since my NavigationDrawer has been implemented with `RecyclerView`, and the 2 TextViews (which I am supposed to update) are assigned to the xml in another class. Precisely, within the `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` class also inside the `RecyclerView.Adapter` class.... How can I tailor your solution to my problem, or, is there another way?

Comment: OK, then you use the constructor of the RecyclerView to pass the values, and create a public method in the RecyclerView to set the textviews. Now when you create the RecyclerView object, pass the values of name and email and call the method to set these values to the view.